# PgBackrest perfom restore without wal files

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.6

Is it possible to restore a full backup from `pgbackrest` without the archive files?

I tried to restore a full backup on another server but when I tried to start the instance via `pg_ctl start` I get an error saying "panic: could not locate a valid checkpoint"

If it is not possible then would it be possible to restore a `pgbackrest` backup over ssh?

PgBackrest - Version: 2.24

PostgreSQL - Version: 9.6

```
pgbackrest --stanza=mystanza restore --process-max 4  --delta --link-all
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to restore from a postgresql binary backup without WAL. Regardless of the backup software was used: pg_basebackup, pgbackrest, barman, wal-e, wal-g or something else that uses a binary copy of the data directory.
Even if case when a postgresql server was completely shut down while the backup was taken. It is mandatory to have WAL segments to start the database system.

---

So, if you have no backup (correct, a basebackup without WAL means no backup) and you want to start the database and *damage your data* - you could try to use [`pg_resetwal`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgresetwal.html). Please read the docs carefully. After that, any anomalies in the data are expected, for example, you may find duplicate rows under a unique constraint, see rows that have already been deleted, or cannot find recently added rows.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. No I don't want to use the pg_resetwal. Is it possible to restore a pgbackrest backup over ssh?

Comment: No. You cannot restore a physical backup without WAL archives.

Comment: Okay I understand that but is it generally possible with pgbackrest to restore backups over ssh ?